# Scanner and validating answers like a dictionary in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I just wanted to practice my java so I made sort of a dictionary.

But I can't get my code to work on the console. Like it doesn't give me any error, it's just that my console in eclipse won't pop up and when I remove the scanner parts it will pop up. Any help is appreciated! Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HeleLijst lijst = new HeleLijst();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Geef een afkorting op: ");
    lijst.all();

    if (lijst.betekenislist.containsKey(input)) {
        System.out.println("De betekenis van " + input + " is: " + lijst.betekenislist.get(input));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Geen correcte afkorting!");
    }

    sc.close();

}
```

Comment: what do you mean: your console won't pop up? that's a bit expected, go to that view yourself. maybe it's just waiting for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The console is waiting for your input... You probably should have printed some kind of message signifying what the input is for